# MVC ignore request for controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a base controller that I want to be ignored if requested, by using the IgnoreRoute method like this `routes.IgnoreRoute("IgnoreThis");` I have been able to match the controller and it is subsequently ignored (returns a 404).

If I enter the following URL http://mysite/IgnoreThis/SomeAction however, the ignored route is no longer matched.

What is the syntax that I need to use in order to use regular expression that matches any route that starts with "IgnoreThis"?

Answer (score 3):

Try this below.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("IgnoreThis/{*pathInfo}");
```